# Retrive firebase object using snapshotchanges

Tags: angular, firebase

I want to retrive one product from my product list using `snanshotChanges`.
Here is my code step by step:

Here's the interface:

```
export interface Product {
  title: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}
```

Here's the Service:

I use db.object to read object from firebase.

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Product } from './models/product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product: Product) {
   return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
  }

  getAll(): AngularFireList<Product> {
    return this.db.list('/products');
  }

  get(productId): AngularFireObject<Product> {
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId);
  }

  }
```

Here's the ProductDetailsComponent Class:

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from 'app/category.service';
import { ProductService } from 'app/product.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$;
  categories;
  product = {};

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService) {
    this.categories = categoryService.getCategories();
    this.categories$ = this.categories.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()}));
     });


  
    const param_id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (param_id) {
       this.productService.get(param_id).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
        return changes.payload.val() })).subscribe(p => this.product = p);

    }
  }


  save(product) {
   this.productService.create(product);
   this.router.navigate(['admin/products']);
   }

   ngOnInit() {






      }
    }
```

Here's the Template:

```
<input 
  #title="ngModel" 
  [(ngModel)] = "product.title" 
  name="title" 
  id="title" 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  required>
```

The Error I'm getting:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
>   Error ERROR TypeError: changes.map is not a function

Comment: I  have checked with other solutions .......I also go for the same

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your current implementation.

1. You have a property named `Product` in your Component Class but then you're using `product` in your template.
2. Also, `Product` will most probably be of type `Observable`. So you'll have to either `subscribe` to it in your Component Class, or you'll have to unwrap it in your template using the `async` pipe.
3. You are using `snapshotChanges` when what you need to use is `valueChanges`. `valueChanges` will give you an `Observable` that you can subscribe to directly. I'm not really sure why you're using `map` and then getting the `key` when you already have the `key` as your `para_ID`.

Give this a try:

```
<div *ngIf="Product | async as product">
  <input 
    #title="ngModel" 
    [(ngModel)] = "product.title" 
    name="title" 
    id="title" 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    required>
</div>
```

Here we're checking if `Product` was initialized and then we're using the `async` pipe and creating an alias named `product` for the unwrapped value.

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want to use the `async` pipe, then you can directly subscribe to the `Observable` instead. Here's how:

```
const para_ID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
if (para_ID) {
  this._product = this.productService.get(para_ID);

  this._product.valueChanges()
    .subscribe(res => this.Product = res);
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<div *ngIf="Product">
  <input 
    #title="ngModel" 
    [(ngModel)] = "Product.title" 
    name="title" 
    id="title" 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    required>
  ...
</div>
```